# Unable to install ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso in Virtualbox

Tags: installation, 13.10, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox-4.3.6-91406-Win on Windows 7 x64 with an AMD 64-bit processor. The virtualbox installation is also a 64-bit install. I've been able to install Win Server 2008. When I try to install ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso in Virtualbox, I get this msg:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, nut only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

I'm using an AMD Phenom II X2 555 processor. It sounds like the .iso file may be corrupt? Any ideas/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you created your virtual machine I think you put less than 4gb of ram and that the computer created is an 32bits so you will have to download the same version for ubuntu.